# Issue in SimpleSAMLphp integration with my application

Tags: service, identity, saml, simplesamlphp

Following is the code which I am using to integrate SAML into my application:

```
require_once('../../sp_saml/lib/_autoload.php');
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('trunk-sp');
$as->requireAuth();
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();
print_r($attributes);
```

The issue which I am getting is with https pages only. It goes to 414 Request URI too long, when trying to authenticate from the SimpleSAMLphp.

Comment: Page is not available.

Comment: Please check I have updated the question details